# How to replace complex ID with number?

Tags: awk

I have a file with multiple entries for each ID number. The file has about 2,000 ID's with 54,000 observations per ID. I need to feed the output into an algorithm that requires ID's to be less than 6 characters. How can I replace the ID's with just the numbers one to 2000? ID in the file looks like this:

```
2007I804567
2007I804567
2007I804567
2007I804568
2007I804568
2007I804568
2007I804569
2007I804569
2007I804569
```

Need it to look like this (want to keep the ID):

```
1 2007I804567
1 2007I804567
1 2007I804567
2 2007I804568
2 2007I804568
2 2007I804568
3 2007I804569
3 2007I804569
3 2007I804569
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to map the unique IDs to a number each (under 1,000,000) and then feed it to the algorithm. The final step will be translating your numbers back into the IDs.

Comment: I though about unique sorting the ID's and then assigning a line number. Then how do I get those line numbers back to the big file?

Comment: You keep what ID was assigned to each number and reverse the process at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat file
2007I804567
2007I804567
2007I804567
2007I804568
2007I804568
2007I804568
2007I804569
2007I804569
2007I804569
$ 
$ awk '!seen[$0]++{++id} {print id, $0}' file
1 2007I804567
1 2007I804567
1 2007I804567
2 2007I804568
2 2007I804568
2 2007I804568
3 2007I804569
3 2007I804569
3 2007I804569
```

Comment: Awesome, that works great thank you. I have a question about what this is doing. Is the ID function recognizing unique lines and assigning that line an ID? This only seems to work when I have a file of just the ID's, otherwise it just ouputs line numbers to the end of the file.

Comment: @jkshah - not necessarily sorted but all same numbers grouped together, as shown in the posted representative sample input. It's a trivial tweak to create a map array if that turns out not to be what the OP wanted after all.

Comment: @EdMorton agree. was thinking in a same line of array mapping and at the same time decoding your code. thanks for clarification.

Comment: @JustinBuchanan it's keeping an array named `seen` indexed by each line's contents, and incrementing the array value every time it sees a duplicate line in the input file, so the first time a line appears, `seen[line]` has the value zero and the id variable gets incremented. I don;t understand the last sentence of your comment but it almost sounds like your posted representative input file is actually NOT the format of your real input file. Obviously, that would be a problem - you need to post a truly representative input file to stand any chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try following `awk`

```
awk '!($0 in id) {id[$0]=++n} {print id[$0], $0}' file
```

**Short Description**

```
awk '
    !($0 in id) {             # if line is not present in array 'id'
         id[$0]=++n           # assign unique ID of a line to incremental number i.e. create an array of id with line a key 
    } 
    {
        print id[$0], $0      # print corresponding ID along with line content
    }' file                   # input file
```